# Best system to store sheet music when in use

Tags: sheet-music

I need a system that I can use to store sheet music that I am currently learning and/or performing. To clear up, I need some sort of folder or display book that will let me store multiple pages of sheet music at once whilst still being able to read and make notes on. This system can be solely for sheet music or another type of folder or be another type of folder that will store A4 sheets. I don't care if I have to buy a folder as well as tabs, I just need to be able to read the sheets clearly and edit them when need being.
I need to use the folder at home while learning or playing a song and on stage.

Comment: An ordinary ring binder does the job. Questions about equipment recommendations are usually not allowed here.

Comment: For writing on... ring binders are good as Tim suggests. On my digi piano I need something lighter so I use a couple of plastic office clipboards which slot in the top - good for writing on too. Sheet changes are clumsy with these though unless you have spares.

Comment: What's wrong with using the original sheet musiccopy and a soft pencil?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for equipment are considered off topic here. You can reword your question to ask about what features you should look for or other related things. Asking about the "best" on is not on topic though.

Comment: By the way I thought this was a question not for recommendations, but looking for opinions on how in general to handle loose sheets while practicing, performing or writing. Agree it probably needs an edit by the questioner to make it clear and get the question on topic.

Comment: Note that looking for opinions specifically is normally not on-topic either. Looking for general advice and facts about storing sheet music **is** definitely on topic, although I think that might be a duplicate.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think "opinions" comprise a majority of the content on this site.  Hopefully educated opinions from folks who are very knowledgeable.   The "rules" seek to avoid questions which can't be answered on a factual basis and are ONLY going to generate opinions and end up looking like a debate with no definitive answer - and perhaps much disagreement. There are thousands of questions (many very highly rated) that solicit "opinions".  "Best system" in the heading 4 this question is the 'best' way to define the question which is really "What systems have been used to ... and will also..?"

Comment: @ToddWilcox Your right - it seems like there was a very similar question recently - only without the expressed desire for an ability to make notes at will on the music.

Comment: @RockinCowboy Yes, it is a slightly different question: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/34711/best-ways-of-storing-sheet-music

Answer (score 1):

I have always used a good old-fashioned 3 ring binder and that does the trick. Easy to store, transport and keep music organized. I organize by composer last name, then by song name to keep it easy. In a 3 ring binder, it's also easy to make a quick notation on the music, which isn't as easy if you have them in a plastic protector or on some sort of tablet. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from obvious solutions, it may be possible to use scanner together with tablet. Scan the sheet music and keep the content on the tablet. A single tablet uses up very little space, is easy to put on then note holder and can contain lots of scanned material.

The negative side is that it is more difficult to read from the tablet and only one page is visible at time. Hence it is more suited to store something you already know well and just need a slight reminder on how the notes go.

Also, buying scanner and tablet just for this purpose looks expensive and may have some learning curve (how to scan, how to transfer to the tablet, etc).